# Can I use "was going to see" with " It was the first time", in case the event has not happened yet

Tags: past-tense

when I got to the Boat Race, I suddenly realised that due to summer exams, work deadlines and other boring stuff, this was the first time I'd seen Freeboy in five months .

What surprises me is that he spoke of the concert as something he had already seen but when he arrived at the Boat Race the concert had  not even  begun. Would it be better to write
this was the first time I was going to see Freeboy in 5 months.

Comment: We often generalize an experience, happening in the present, into a "unit," without distinguishing between the moments in it. E.g., if I start driving toward the beach, two hours away, I might say "This is the first time I've been to the beach this year," even though I'm just starting the process.

Comment: More precisely, *...this **would be** the first time I'd seen Freeboy in five months*. Even more precisely, *...this **would be** the first time I **would have seen** Freeboy in five months*, but nobody really cares about that pointless level of verb tweaking in English.

Comment: Would the first time I would see can work too